# Why does echo use a different value of loop-variable than set?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am attempting to use a simple for-loop to create a series of strings followed by a number. However, when I try to add the iterator-variable to the end of the strings, the value which is added is instead the endpoint of the loop.

A simplified version of the script is:

```
@echo off

set STARTSTRING="Test-

for /l %%x in (1, 1, 26) do (
    echo %%x
    set CONCATENATED_STRING=%STARTSTRING%%%x"
    echo %CONCATENATED_STRING%
)
pause
```

Which gives the output:

[image]

Can someone please explain to me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, the **entire** block is parsed and **then** executed. Any `%var%` within the block will be replaced by that variable's value **at the time the block is parsed** - before the block is executed - the same thing applies to a `FOR ... DO (block)`.

Hence, `IF (something) else (somethingelse)` will be executed using the values of `%variables%` at the time the `IF` is encountered.

Two common ways to overcome this are 1) to use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and use `!var!` in place of `%var%` to access the changed value of `var` or 2) to call a subroutine to perform further processing using the changed values.

So -

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "STARTSTRING=Test-"

for /l %%x in (1, 1, 26) do (
    echo %%x
    set "CONCATENATED_STRING=!STARTSTRING!%%x"
    echo !CONCATENATED_STRING!
)
pause
```

Note the positioning of the quotes (so that stray spaces on the ends of lines are not allocated to the variable.)

`!var!` accesses the run-time value of the variable in `delayedexpansion` mode - `%var%` the parse-time value

The `setlocal` also ensures that when the batch ends, any changes made to the environment variables is discarded. Withou it, as you have seen, the variable retains its value as set on the previous batch-run.

Comment: With a bit of trying and failing this worked perfectly - I was a bit surprised that I didn't need to escape quotes I wanted in the string inside the set-statement though!